# CosmosDB connector - Error while compiling(dependency path issue)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ballerina

I am facing an issue while trying to build the CosmosDB Connector from the [Ballerina Azure CosmosDB GitHub repository](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-azure-cosmosdb/tree/main). The error message I encounter is as follows:

```
ERROR [Ballerina.toml:(16:1,16:65)] could not locate dependency path '../cosmosdb-native/build/libs/cosmosdb-native-4.0.0.jar'
```

Comment: fyi this isn't a programming question and is off-topic. It's really a topic for the tool's repo.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the `bal build` command, it's important to ensure that the necessary dependencies are built. To do this, execute the following command from the root level of the repository:

```
./gradlew build
```